sending multipart file data as byte array with customer header using rest template is showing empty multiparts at receiver side
I am sending multipart file data as byte array using ByteArrayResource with custom header for every form field.
The source class used to wrap file data
public class VehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource extends ByteArrayResource {

    private final String fileName;
    public VehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource(byte[] byteArray,String fileName) {
        super(byteArray);
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}

The code to form request of multitype/form-data with every part of form having headers
public MultiValueMap<String, Object> getVehicleInspectPhotoRequestMap(MultiValueMap<String, Part> fileParts) {
        return fileParts.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    try {
                        VehicleInspectionPhoto vehicleInspectionPhoto = createVehicleInspectionPhoto(entry);
                        HttpHeaders httpHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
                        httpHeaders.set("Doctype","INSPECTION");
                        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(0).getContentType()));
                        httpHeaders.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.formData().filename(vehicleInspectionPhoto.getFilename()).build());
                        VehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource vehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource=
                                new VehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource(vehicleInspectionPhoto.getBytes(), vehicleInspectionPhoto.getFilename());
                        HttpEntity<VehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource> httpEntity=new HttpEntity<>(vehicleInspectionPhotoUploadResource,httpHeaders);
                        return Map.entry(entry.getKey(), httpEntity);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> List.of(entry.getValue()), (k1, k2) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("merging error");
                }, LinkedMultiValueMap::new));

    }

The rest template code where the above created param is passed
public void handlerAsync1(MultiValueMap<String,Object> multiValueMap) {

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multiValueMap);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/receiveMap", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
            log.info(responseEntity.getBody());
            log.info(responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString());
        } catch (RestClientResponseException restClientResponseException) {
            log.error( "Error::{}",restClientResponseException);
            throw restClientResponseException;
        }
    }

Below is the piece of code to read the data,
@PostMapping(value = "/receiveMap")
    public ResponseEntity<String> receiveInspectionPhotosForm(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap,
                                                          @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        if (!multiValueMap.containsKey("abc")) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("received");
    }

The issue i am facing is that i am getting empty map above. Even when parameter is of type MultiValueMap<String,Part> the map is empty.Can someone please help me on this?
